# My mysql query (with join, temporary column and order by coalesce) is very slow

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, sql-order-by, coalesce

I have an SQL query that is too slow, and I need help to optimize it. I have three tables that contains books and metadata on books.

```
Books
-BookID (primary key)
-BookTitle
-Author
-Year

Editions
-EditionID (primary key)
-BookID
-Publisher
-Year

Printings
-PrintID (primary key)
-EditionID
-PrintDate
-Binding
```

One book (e.g. Treasure Island by Robert Louis Stevenson) can have many editions, and each edition can have several printings. I am trying to make a list of all the books and their corresponding first edition (just the very first printing of any edition). Note that each book is associated with a field Year the book was created. E.g., Treasure Island was written in 1881 and published serialized, the first edition was published in 1883). If a book has no first editions in the printings-table, the Year-field from the table of Books shall be used.

I have the following query that makes a temporary column named FirstEdition together with the book data:

```
SELECT 
    BookID,
    BookTitle,
    Author,
    Year,
    (SELECT MIN(PrintDate) FROM Editions E LEFT JOIN Printings P ON E.EditionID=P.EditionID WHERE E.BookID=B.BookID) as FirstEdition
FROM Books B
ORDER BY COALESCE(FirstEdition,Year)
```

This gives me a list of all the books, sorted by the first printed edition (if set) or by the year created if it is unpublished. The problem is that with thousands of books and several editions and many printings of each edition, my query takes 12 seconds to perform on my server. If I replace the ORDER BY-clause with

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(Year)
```

the same query takes 0.2 seconds. I can only conclude that the cause of the slow speed is that the temporary column combined with the coalesce. My research has brought up the following related question: [mysql - Optimizing ORDER BY COALESCE on joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759514/mysql-optimizing-order-by-coalesce-on-joined-table-column)

The solution in this case was to change the database structure and queries. That is not an option here. Is there anything else I can try?

```
SELECT * FROM Books B LEFT JOIN Editions E ON E.BookID=B.BookID LEFT JOIN Printings P ON P.EditionID=E.EditionID
GROUP BY B.BookID
ORDER BY COALESCE(P.PrintDate,B.Year)
```

I have tried to remove the subquery so that all the tables are completely joined to give them indexes. This query takes 28 seconds. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `EXPAIN` to see where you need an index

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using the MariaDB10-package that are included on Synology line of home servers. mysql -V gives this info: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.62-MariaDB, for Linux () using readline 5.1

Comment: I mean the server version, not that of any client. What does `select version();` say?

Comment: select version(); gives 10.3.21-MariaDB

Comment: @jens: the EXPLAIN command gives me information that mysql uses the primary index on table B, but DEPENDENT SUBQUERY on tables E and P. I'm not sure what to do with this information

Comment: Post the TEXT output of EXPLAIN output so we can see what the optimizer has done with your query, please.

Comment: Unclear.  For example, which table is `PrintDate` in?  Please qualify each column with the table (or alias).  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.